# Oracle UPDATE statement using the `REPLACE` function

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, sql-update

I am trying to remember how form a proper `REPLACE` statement in Oracle SQL.

In essence, I need to perform a `REPLACE` over a few thousand records in which `column1` and `column2` may contain a value of `'14'`. If they do, I need to replace it with just a space character.

I know that the syntax is something like the following, but I can't seem to get it quite right:

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET ('column1', 'column2') = REPLACE(?????????????)
WHERE 'column1' IN ('14') AND 'column2' NOT LIKE ('4%')
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 22):

The query should look something like:

```
UPDATE table1
SET column1 = REPLACE(column1, '14', ' '),
    column2 = REPLACE(column2, '14', ' ')
WHERE column1 LIKE '%14%' OR column2 LIKE '%14%'
```

Comment: REPLACE(Column1, '14', '') should be REPLACE(Column1, '14', ' ')  ;)

Comment: "UPDATE TABLE" is not a valid DML statement in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE TABLENAME
  SET COLUMN1 = ' ',
  SET COLUMN2 = ' '
WHERE COLUMN1='14' OR COLUMN2='14';
```

Assuming Column[1,2] are of Character type.

Answer (score -2):

SYNATX:

```
UPDATE TABLENAME
SET
COLUMNNAME = REPLACE(COLUMN/TEXT,'FROMREPLACE','TOREPLACE')
WHERE CONDITION;
```

EXAMPLE:

```
UPADTE ER_FORMSLINEAR
SET col59 = REPLACE(col59,'[Umbilical Artery Catheter (UAC) or Peripheral Arterial Access]','[Umbilical Artery Catheter (UAC)]')
from ER_FORMSLINEAR
where fk_form=327 and col59 like '%[Umbilical Artery Catheter (UAC) or Peripheral Arterial Access]%';
```

Comment: this is best example. before you update, you can use the replace function in select statement. Like: select col59 as "Admission Lines and Tubes", 
REPLACE(col59,'[Umbilical Artery Catheter (UAC) or Peripheral Arterial Access]','[Umbilical Artery Catheter (UAC)]') 
as "Updated_Admission Lines and Tubes" 
from er_formslinear
where fk_form=327 and col59 like '%[Umbilical Artery Catheter (UAC) or Peripheral Arterial Access]%';